# Create new column by adding conditions on rows in data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

Like the title, it's complicated to describe , so I'll just show the code , what I got and what I want it to be.

```
set.seed(1)
df<-data.frame('X1'=rnorm(10),
               'X2'=rnorm(10),
               'X3'=c(c(rep('A',5)),c(rep('B',5))))

## create a bew column 'SPX2' which is the smallest positive number OF X2 
## of each group(A and B)

require(data.table)
setDT(df)[X2>0,SPX2:=min(X2),by=X3]
df
```

then I got the result as:

```
            X1          X2 X3      SPX2
 1: -0.6264538  1.51178117  A 0.3898432
 2:  0.1836433  0.38984324  A 0.3898432
 3: -0.8356286 -0.62124058  A        NA
 4:  1.5952808 -2.21469989  A        NA
 5:  0.3295078  1.12493092  A 0.3898432
 6: -0.8204684 -0.04493361  B        NA
 7:  0.4874291 -0.01619026  B        NA
 8:  0.7383247  0.94383621  B 0.5939013
 9:  0.5757814  0.82122120  B 0.5939013
10: -0.3053884  0.59390132  B 0.5939013
```

and what I want is :

```
            X1          X2 X3      SPX2
 1: -0.6264538  1.51178117  A 0.3898432
 2:  0.1836433  0.38984324  A 0.3898432
 3: -0.8356286 -0.62124058  A 0.3898432
 4:  1.5952808 -2.21469989  A 0.3898432
 5:  0.3295078  1.12493092  A 0.3898432
 6: -0.8204684 -0.04493361  B 0.5939013
 7:  0.4874291 -0.01619026  B 0.5939013
 8:  0.7383247  0.94383621  B 0.5939013
 9:  0.5757814  0.82122120  B 0.5939013
10: -0.3053884  0.59390132  B 0.5939013
```

cause I want to create a new column `df$X4<-df$SPX2 - df$X2`,o any other operations that require `SPX2` to be like above.
I did my search and found several posts like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513901/r-data-table-adding-new-column-for-subset-of-rows-conditional-on-all-rows) , but that's not what I try do here.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: This should work: `setDT(df)[,SPX2:=min(X2[X2 > 0]),by=X3]`. I've added the condition to the minimum clause so that the minimum is taken over all X2 which are greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks @jav, your code is checked ,worked perfectly. Never aware of imposing conditions like that, enlightening! Why not you put it as answer and with a little explanation about why we could do `X2[X2 > 0]`  here for others who need it and me to learn. I could take it as answer for this question by the way.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah for your edition , it made the question much more readable and understandable. I'll be aware of these kind of problems with future posts I may make.

Comment: @jav You may want to add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JasonGoal, added as an answer, with some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidyverse` alternative:

```
df %>%
  group_by(X3) %>%
  mutate(SPX2 = min(X2[X2>0]))
```

which gives:

```
           X1          X2     X3      SPX2
        <dbl>       <dbl> <fctr>     <dbl>
 1 -0.6264538  1.51178117      A 0.3898432
 2  0.1836433  0.38984324      A 0.3898432
 3 -0.8356286 -0.62124058      A 0.3898432
 4  1.5952808 -2.21469989      A 0.3898432
 5  0.3295078  1.12493092      A 0.3898432
 6 -0.8204684 -0.04493361      B 0.5939013
 7  0.4874291 -0.01619026      B 0.5939013
 8  0.7383247  0.94383621      B 0.5939013
 9  0.5757814  0.82122120      B 0.5939013
10 -0.3053884  0.59390132      B 0.5939013
```

Comment: Thanks@Aramis7d, good solution, I took it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `data.table` package:

```
setDT(df)    
df[,SPX2:=min(X2[X2 > 0]),by=X3]
```

What this does is for each value of `X3`, subset on positive values of `X2` (i.e. `X2[X2 > 0]`) and then take the minimum over all positive values. Note that if there are no positive values (i.e. `X2[X2 > 0]` is empty), then the resulting value would be `Inf`. Keep this in mind especially if you want to do any further calculations using `SPX2`.

As per your question why `X2[X2 > 0]` works, think about it as follows: For each value of `X3`, a vector of corresponding values of `X2` is returned. Now, you can just perform regular vector operations on this vector, one of which is subsetting via `X2 > 0`. It works much like the following:

```
x2 = c(-1, 1, 2, 3, -2, 4)
x2[x2 > 0]
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Hope this helps!